# In the sentence below, is the verb 'render' used correctly?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs, word-usage

Consider the sentence:

> What matters is to render the idea from the field of theory into
>   practice.

Could the verb *render* be replaced by the verb *translate* without changing the meaning? Which is the better choice? If neither is a good choice, can you think of a more appropriate verb?

Comment: [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/render) gives a sense that could be considered to license this usage: **render** (9) to translate (something) into another language or form. AHDEL (same link) restricts the allowable DO of the verb in its 'transfer' sense tightly: **render** 1f. To transfer (a suspect or prisoner) from one country to another by rendition. I'd go with Silenus, and say 'allowable but clunky'.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more precise in what I was driving at. Your answers show, however, that you got my point. You´ve been of great help, indeed! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think the sentence sounds a bit clumsy (maybe because of the redundancy of talking about *both* an idea *and* theory, and the redundancy of using "field of").

I would prefer the following:

- What matters is how we ***translate*** the theory into practice.
- What matters is how we ***translate*** the idea into practice.
- What matters is how we ***execute*** the idea.
- What matters is how we ***put*** the idea ***into practice***.
- What matters is to ***render*** the idea practicable.
- What matters is to ***render*** the idea into practice.

EDIT:

For whatever reason, "render" (when used with an object) appears to disallow proximity to the "from"-headed preposition, making the structure you ask about sound funny. For example, (1) seems fine but (2) seems marked.

1. The translator rendered 'dog' into French.
2. *The translator rendered 'dog' **from** English **into** French.

Interestingly, if you invert the prepositional phrases, it sounds better.

3. The translator rendered 'dog' **into** French **from** English.

I'm not sure why this would be. But note that other change of state verbs (e.g. "change") also seem to favor a certain prepositional order:

4. The witch changed John **from** a man **into** a pig.
5. *The witch changed John **into** a pig **from** a man.

(4) sounds fine. (5) sounds a bit off.

One reason "render" might necessarily take the "into"-preposition before the "from"-preposition is that the "into"-preposition is what's called a *complement* of it, whereas the "from"-proposition is an optional *adjunct*. Complements of verbs always appear closer to the verbs than their adjuncts.

Comment: I see your point. Thanks for the alternative versions, which sound much better, of course. Quite apart from the clumsiness, however, what I had in mind was whether the structure render/translate ... from ... into is correct.

Comment: In the OED under the entry render v. I found the following example, which is quite dated. That´s why I`d like to know if this structure: render  from … into still works.

 III. 14. To bring (one) into a state or condition (obs.); also, to cause to be in a certain state. rare.  1490 Caxton Eneydos ix. 37 That it maye playse the‥to rendre theym from theyr lacyuyte in-to‥shamefaste chastyte.    
@Silenus

Comment: That´s a good point, which had never come to my mind. But what do you make of this structure to express transition from one field/realm to another?
E.g: “The term has been rendered by analogy from psychology into sociology.”
And what about the verbs translate, extend/expand instead of render in this context? @Silenus

Answer (score 0):

I go for *translate*.

There are, however, other options, depending on the situation in which the statement is made. Equally good, then, might be any of the following:

> - drag (especially if there is resistance to getting practical, or getting one's hands dirty)
> - morph
> - transform
> - bring
> - transmogrify
> - transfer
> - translate
> - carry
> - transplant
> - graft (this is a neat one, imho)
> - remove . . . and plug/put it into practice
> - to allow the idea to undergo metamorphosis from theoretical to practical
> - to remove it from the realm of theory and put it into practice
> - to take the idea and transform it from theory into practice
> - to pull the idea from the realm of theory into the realm of practice

Comment: Thanks for the chart to choose from! What about the verb transfer in the above context? Would it work: transfer from ... into?

Comment: @YogiBear: Yeah, I guess "transfer" would work, albeit not very elegantly. If you're after elegant, I'd use the word graft; it oozes elegance. Although as I've said, "translate" ain't too shabby, nor is the simple "bring the idea from theory into practice. There are others, too. I'll likely think up some more. When I do, I'll let you know. Don